prove that $n - \phi(n)$ is a square where $n$ is an even perfect number
where even perfect numbers are of the form $2^{p-1}(2^{p} - 1)$
( $p$ and $2^{p} - 1$ are prime numbers )
My attempt
$\phi(n)$ = ($2^{p - 1} - 2$)($2^{p} - 2$)
So, we need to prove that.
$2^{p - 1}$($2^{p} - 1$) -  ($2^{p - 1} - 2$)($2^{p} - 2$)
is a perfect square,
I played around with it, and I ended up with -
$(5(2^{p - 1}) + 2)$
$2^{p-1}$ reminds me of Fermat's theorem, but I doubt it'll be helpful here.
Is there a way to factorise it so it's apparent that it is a perfect square?
Hints would be appreciated. Thanks in advance for the excellent answers!
Source-
Olympiad mathematics by pathfinder

The first factor of $\phi(n)$ should be $2^{p-1}-2^{p-2}$

@ameg I'm sorry, but when I try expanding it I get $2^{2p - 1}$ - $2^{p + 1}$ + 2?

What I means is that if $m=p_1^{a_1}...p_k^{a_k}$ is the prime factorization of $m$, then $\phi(m)=(p_1^{a_1}-p_1^{a_1-1})...(p_k^{a_k}-p_k^{a_k-1})$. Since $2^{p-1}(2^{p}-1)$ is the prime factorization of your $n$, then $\phi(n)=(2^{p-1}-2^{p-2})(2^p-1-(2^p-1)^2)$. The first factor being $2^{p-1}-2^{p-2}$, but you wrote $2^{p-1}-2$.

If you fix that, the computation of $n-\phi(n)$ should give you $2^{2p-1}$, which is not a square.

You mean $2^p-1$ is prime (not $2^{p-1}$, which is certainly not prime for any $p\ge 3$).

@TonyK Sorry, my bad. I have edited it. Thanks for pointing it out!

We have $\varphi(n)=2^{p-2}(2^p-2)$ hence $$n-\varphi(n)=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)-2^{p-2}(2^p-2)=2^{p-2}2^p-2^{p-1}+2^{p-1}=2^{2p-2}=(2^{p-1})^2$$

I’m sorry, but what about $2^{2p - 1}$ you get from the first bracket? $(2^{p - 1})(2^{p} - 1)$

Note $2^{p-1}\cdot 2^p-2^{p-2}\cdot 2^p=2^{p-2}2^p(2-1)$ , the other two terms cancel out.
